# Reading formdata binary excel in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel-import

I am sending excel in formdata() property from reactJs as follows

```
let formData = new FormData(), headers = {};

headers['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data';
headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';

formData.append('dataFile', file);

let res = await axios({
    method: 'POST',
    headers,
    url: '/api/products/general-excel-import',
    data: formData
});
```

At my **backend route** is defined as

```
api.post(
  "/api/products/general-excel-import",
  [multer.any()],
  productController.generalExcelImport
);
```

And my **controller function**:

```
const excelToJson = require('convert-excel-to-json');

exports.generalExcelImport = async function(req, res) {
  const file = req.files[0];
  
  console.log({ file: file});

  const jsonData = excelToJson({sourceFile: file.buffer });
  return res.status(200).send({ data: jsonData, message: 'Imported successfully' });  
}
```

The `console.log` in controller outputs the following object in terminal

```
file: {
  fieldname: 'dataFile',
  originalname: 'findings.xlsx',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
  buffer: <Buffer 50 4b 03 04 14 00 06 00 08 00 00 00 21 00 62 ee 9d 68 5e 01 00 00 90 04 00 00 13 00 08 02 5b 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 5f 54 79 70 65 73 5d 2e 78 6d 6c 20 ... 9091 more bytes>,
  size: 9141
}
```

when the request is made at backend route it throws the following error

> [0] TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of
> type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received an instance of
> Object

can any one tell where i'm wrong in code

Comment: Try using `source` instead of `sourceFile` in the call to `excelToJson`.

Comment: @MosheKatz i tried that also, it the error changes to `f.slice is not a function`